# BI in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I want to develop BI in SharePoint. Could you please provide for me solution or how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is powerful tools in SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise for Business Intelligence, like Power View to visualize data. More about it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213579(v=sql.110).aspx
Note that it requires Enterprise Edition for SharePoint 2013 and at lest SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence Edition.